# Annual Memberships Renewed Early

Tags: civimember

We have memberships that are "fixed" from Jan 1 through Dec 31. This works fine except for that we want that if anyone creates or renews a membership in November or December, that their membership will be valid for this year and next year.

So if I create/renew my Membership in September 2019, I will be a member from then until December 2019.

But if I create/renew my Membership in November 2019, I will be a member from then until December **2020**. Here I will get Nov/Dec of this year "for free" and then be a member for all of next year.

Presently, if I create/renew a Membership in November 2019, it ends December 2019.

Comment: Can you confirm that you mean this "Presently, if I renew my Membership in November 2019, it ends December 2019" or are you saying join/renew but do not have evidence of the problem existing when renewing? Karin's answer would be the right solution but if you are not seeing 1 year added to the End Date when someone renews then i think you have a separate problem

Comment: Pls explain if you are using Rollover date, and if so how.

Comment: KarinG's answer is correct -- now I see that. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to configure the rollover date in the Membership Configuration. Please see:

https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/membership/defining-memberships/

Comment: I see why this would fix the problem with New memberships, not sure I see why this solves the issue for Renewing members.

Comment: There is no problem with Renewing Memberships -> if you renew at any time during an existing year CiviCRM adds +1y

Comment: Hi Karin. I didn't mean to imply there was a problem with your answer, more that the question implied that when they were renewing they were only getting a couple of months added "Presently, if I create/renew my Membership in November 2019, it ends December 2019" hence i wondered if there was more to their problem than 'rollover date'

Comment: i added a comment to the Q to get clarification. i may just be misreading things

Comment: Ah I see - I doubt there is a problem with renewals - unless perhapas they have configured it to be rolling when trying to do calendar year which is fixed?